# Does attack speed modify the animation speed for priests on TERA?

Tags: tera

Good Day,

I am figuring out how to build my priest on TERA. I have recently seen a video of a sorcerer with 24% attack speed landing his attacks faster than when he had 0% attack speed. I wondered if the same goes for healers? **Would attack speed affect the animation speed of which your character gets heals off?** (I am not talking about cast times - but I do notice that you cannot act while your character is animating on his attack or heal)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this guy's guide](http://teratoday.com/content/tera-guide/tera-class-guide/tera-priest-guide-ifris), about half way down in Gear Stats, attack speed is indeed a critical stat, as it does increase your healing animations' speed according to this line:

> This bonus is quite noticeable and important for priests. **It increases
>   all our healing animations**, including circles and even target heals.
>   This is a must and you should aim to have two of these rolled on your
>   enigmatic staff. At the example above, the staff has "double" attack
>   speed stats rolled.

[This guide](http://teracodex.com/guide/21046) also states that attack speed is a useful stat when it goes over all of the stats.

> Which of these affect a Healer's raw healing power?
>
> None of them! Pretty cool, huh? Our heals cannot crit and Power/Attack
>   only affect damage dealers. **The only combat stat or stat modifier
>   that's of benefit to a healer is Attack Speed.** That allows us to get
>   off our healing and buff abilities faster, so it's something to look
>   out for.

Finally, someone on [these forums](http://tera-forums.enmasse.com/forums/general-discussion/topics/Unraveling-the-Mysteries-of-Attack-Speed) says that you **heal faster** with it. That topic is from 2012, and it says that there can be disadvantages to attack speed. This mostly seems to be the ranges of melee attacks. These range changes could have changed since this post.

Overall, I've seen several places say that it increases your healing speed, so at the very least, it shouldn't hurt it.

Comment: Finally. a solid answer. I read the links you gave me.

Comment: I will award bounty in 23 hours from now

Comment: Awarded! wasn't exactly 23 hours, but I'm drunk. whatcanyado